# How to synchronous in sqlserver 2008 R2 between A and B?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, synchronous

Fro example~There are 2 or more identical databases in different servers.Now I would like to update a little data with DataBase_A.The question is how to synchronous the other(s) except for Backuping by the 'bak' file.

Answer (score 0):

These methods might help you

- [Sql replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)
- [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx)
- [Linked Servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

I have experienced the same problem and solved it using Linked servers. [Here](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-add-sql-server-linked-server.aspx) is a simple tutorial on creating linked server.
And we could query it like:

```
select * from LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps.